# QT html and CSS to create pdf without QWebEngineView

Tags: html, c++, css, qt, pdf

I want to create a pdf file from html and CSS file. Currently I am trying with QT using QWebView as QwebEngineView is not supported for Ubuntu as there is not MVC2013 or chromium.

I want the creator to be platform independent. I am showing all code here

```
QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

    QFile  htmlFile ("myhtml.html");
    if (!htmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        return -1;
    }


    QWebView *pWebView = new QWebView();
    pWebView->load( QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(htmlFile).path()) );


    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);

    printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");

    pWebView->print(&printer);
    delete pWebView;
```

The html file is as follows

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> <center> ULTRA TECH LABORATORIES PRIVATE LIMITED </center> </h1>
    <h3> <center> CLOTH MARKET, G.E. ROAD KUMHARI, DIST-DRUG(C.G.) </center> </h3>
    <h1> <center> TLD MONITORING SERVICE - DOSE REPORT </center> </h1>
    <p>
        INSTITUTION NO. 017303
        <span>SERVICE PERIOD: APR-JUN 2012</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        ASHOK LABORATORY, KOLKATA
        <span>SERVICE FREQUENCY: QUARTERLY</span>
    </p>
    <center>
        <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum dolor</li>
        <li>sit amet</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        </ul>
    </center>
</body>
```

The CSS file is as follows

```
  ul {
    width: 500px;
    }
li {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}

p {
    text-align:left;
}
span {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: I have also tried QWebView::setHtml() and QWebView::setDefaultStyleSheet() They also give unformatted output.

Comment: I am finding this library wkhtmltopdf which uses the QtWebKit for this. I am trying to find out how they do it but the code is messed up cant understand.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, replace

```
pWebView->load( QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(htmlFile).path()) );
```

to

```
pWebView->load( QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(htmlFile).absoluteFilePath()) );
```

I don't change something in html or css. Css is located near the html.

Then, implement saving to pdf in slot connected to `loadFinished` signal. Because when you save page to pdf it may be not loaded yet.

```
connect (pWebView,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this,SLOT(savePDF(bool)));
```

and

```
void Form::savePDF(bool ok)
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");
    ui->webView->print(&printer);
}
```

After it your code work for me.

**Edit:**

I use `Form` class just for testing, you need put code to your class.

form.h :

```
class Form: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QObject * parent = 0);

private:
    QWebView* webView;

private slots:
    void savePDF(bool ok);
};
```

form.cpp :

```
Form::Form(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{

    webView = new QWebView();
    QFile  htmlFile ("html/index.html");
    if (!htmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug()<<"nosuch file";
    }
    webView->load( QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(htmlFile).absoluteFilePath()) );
    connect (webView,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this,SLOT(savePDF(bool)));
    webView->show();  //comment it to hide webview windows
}

void Form::savePDF(bool ok)
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");
    webView->print(&printer);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me all the files? What is Form class? Where did you write the connect function?

Comment: Object::connect: No such slot MainWindow::savePDF(bool) this error came in my code at runtime.